# Select several lines untill a specific symbol

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I have the next lines of text in a file:

```
eslint.vim
flow.vim
jscs.vim
jshint.vim
standard.vim
xo.vim
```

How can I yank names (without '.vim' part)?

Even better would be to format it to look like this:

```
'eslint', 'flow', 'jscs', 'jshint', 'standard', 'xo'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to use two substitute commands:

First remove the `.vim` part, join all the lines and add comma between the words:

```
:'<,'>s/.vim/\n/, /
```

That will give you this:

```
eslint, flow, jscs, jshint, standard, xo,
```

Then surround the words with quotes:

```
:s/\w\+/'\0'/g
```

You'll get:

```
'eslint', 'flow', 'jscs', 'jshint', 'standard', 'xo',
```

Note the last comma that you might need to delete with `$x` for example.

Comment: typo, extra `/` in first command between vim and \n... the two substitutes can be combined `:'<,'>s/\v(\w+)\.vim\n/'\1', /g`.... and trailing would be `,` and space not just `,`